# If A is Orthogonal (mxm) matrix and (I+A) is invertible THEN Prove --> $ (I-A) (I+A)^{-1} $ is an Skew-Symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

The doctor give us Question want to Prove that:

> If A is Orthogonal (mxm) matrix and (I+A) is invertible THEN Prove --> $$ (I-A) 
>  (I+A)^{-1}  $$ is an Skew-Symmetric matrix

**My Question**

**1)** how to Prove his Question ?....Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could write $I$ as $AA^t$ and as $A^tA$.

Answer (score 0):

$(I-A^\top)(I+A)=-A^\top+A=-(I+A^\top)(I-A)\Rightarrow (I+A^\top)^{-1}(I+A^\top)=- (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}. $

Because $(X^\top)^{-1}=(X^{-1})^\top$ and $X^\top Y^\top=(YX)^\top$ we have $(I+A^\top)^{-1}(I+A^\top)=[(I+A)(I+A)^{-1}]^\top$ and won.

Comment: Can you write explaination step by step let the above equation is" D" ..Show me how is $ D = -D^{t} $ ?